# Form being submitted twice (AJAX)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

For some reason every time I submit my form the AJAX function is called twice in the network tab. I have no idea why this is happening I have another ajax function on my site that doesn't do this so I must have gone wrong somewhere. I see that many other have asked this question on here but none of their solutions help me.

Here's my full JS/AJAX code;

```
// submit form function
jQuery('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $ = jQuery; 
    var filter = $('#form');
    var form_data = $('#form').serializeArray();
    $('#load_more').data('page', 1);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function(response){
            $('#loop').empty();

            for( var i = 0; i < response.post_cont.length; i++ ){
                var html =''+
                    '<div class="col-4">'+
                        '<a href="'+ response.post_cont[i].permalink +'">'+
                            '<div class="card" style="width: 100%;">'+
                                '<div class="post_image" style="background-image: url('+ response.post_cont[i].image +');"></div>'+

                                '<div class="card-body">'+
                                    '<h5 class="card-title">'+ response.post_cont[i].title +'</h5>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</a>'+
                    '</div>';

                $('#loop').append(html);
            }

            if( jQuery('#loop .card').length < response.max_posts[0].no_of_posts){
                $('#load_more').show();
            }else{
                $('#load_more').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});

// button function for form filters
jQuery('#form .option').click(function(){
    var $ = jQuery;
    $('#form .option').removeClass('active');

    var elem = $(this);
    var input = elem.children('input');
    input.click();
    elem.addClass('active');

    $('#form').submit();
});
```

And here's my html;

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="POST" id="form">

        <div id="filters">
            <div class="option">
                <p>Assisted Needs/Residential</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Assisted Needs/Residential">
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <p>Commercial</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Commercial">
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <p>Private Housing</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Private Housing">
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <p>Social Housing</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Social Housing">
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="filter">
    </form>

    <div id="loop" class="row">

    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto">  
            <a id="load_more" href="javascript:;" data-page="1"><p>More</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the server doing some sort of redirect perhaps? This blog covers the kinds of thing you might look for: https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/302-found

Comment: @JGFMK I doubt it as I have another AJAX function that doesn't do this

Comment: did you read my update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to your `input.click()` call. This raises a click event on every checkbox, which is caught and in turn submits the `form` again. Just remove that line.

Also note that you can alias the `jQuery` variable by using the first argument in the document.ready handler, so you can remove the repeated unnecessary `var $ = jQuery` line.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var filter = $('#form');
    var form_data = $('#form').serializeArray();
    $('#load_more').data('page', 1);

    // your ajax call here...
    console.log('making an AJAX request...');
  });

  // button function for form filters
  $('#form .option').click(function() {
    $('#form .option').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#form').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    <div id="filters">
      <div class="option">
        <p>Assisted Needs/Residential</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Assisted Needs/Residential">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <p>Commercial</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Commercial">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <p>Private Housing</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Private Housing">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <p>Social Housing</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Social Housing">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="filter">
  </form>
  <div id="loop" class="row"></div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <a id="load_more" href="javascript:;" data-page="1">
        <p>More</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wrote that answer 8 mins before your answer and you get +2 :) I'll delete my answer. You can collect all points.

Comment: You don't have to delete yours. When I started writing this answer yours was only suggesting to add the `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: Thanks this works now. But I thought I was only applying the click event to just one input not them all. As I am getting the child input of the clicked option.